# How can I pass multiple parameters through a pipeline?

Tags: powershell, parameters, pipeline

I am trying to pass two parameters to a function through the pipeline but it does not appear to work as expected and I am struggling to understand why.

### MWE

```
function Test-Pipeline {
  [CmdletBinding ()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][String]$Name,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][String]$Value
  )
  Write-Host "Name: $Name"
  Write-Host "Value: $Value"
}

"Name", "Value" | Test-Pipeline
```

### Output

> Name: Value
>
> Value: Value

I tried running the `Trace-Command` command to see what was happening. On line 35 we can see that `Value` is bound to `$Parameter`.

Why is PowerShell binding the second input to both parameters? If this is expected, why does it occur only for the second parameter and not for the first?

### Trace

```
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Test-Pipeline]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Test-Pipeline]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Test-Pipeline]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [] to parameter [Name]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION:
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [] to param [Name] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [] to parameter [Value]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION:
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [] to param [Value] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Test-Pipeline]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.String]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [Value] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Name] to parameter [Value]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: Name
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Name] to param [Value] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [Name] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Name] to parameter [Name]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: Name
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Name] to param [Name] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Test-Pipeline]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Test-Pipeline]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.String]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [Name] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Value] to parameter [Name]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: Value
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Value] to param [Name] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [Value] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Value] to parameter [Value]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: Value
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Value] to param [Value] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Test-Pipeline]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND NAMED cmd line args [Write-Host]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Write-Host]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND REMAININGARGUMENTS cmd line args to param: [Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]] to parameter [Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             COERCE arg to [System.Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             BIND arg [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]] to param [Object] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Write-Host]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     CALLING BeginProcessing
Name: Value
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND NAMED cmd line args [Write-Host]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Write-Host]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND REMAININGARGUMENTS cmd line args to param: [Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]] to parameter [Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             COERCE arg to [System.Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             BIND arg [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]] to param [Object] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Write-Host]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     CALLING BeginProcessing
Value: Value
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     CALLING EndProcessing
```

Comment: my understanding is that only ONE parameter per parameter set can be "by pipeline". ///// plus, the pipeline only sends ONE item at a time across the pipe ... so your function only gets one item at a time, processes it, sends it out, and then gets the next item. ///// you need to send an object that has at least one property that binds to _exactly_ one of your parameters. then the other one can get assigned to the remaining parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the comment from Lee Dailey, you can only have one parameter accept input from the Pipeline by "Value" (for each value type, e.g string, int etc.). What your code is currently doing is sending an array of string values, which would then be processed one at a time through the pipeline.

If you want to send in multiple values together in to the Pipeline, you could do so by making those values the properties of a custom object, and then you can accept them via the pipeline by using `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` parameters. This works by matching any properties of the input object that have the same name as input parameters:

```
function Test-Pipeline {
  [CmdletBinding ()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String]$Name,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String]$Value
  )
  Write-Host "Name: $Name"
  Write-Host "Value: $Value"
}

$MyObject = [pscustomobject]@{
    Name = "MyName"
    Value = "MyValue"
}

$MyObject | Test-Pipeline
```

Result:

```
Name: MyName
Value: MyValue
```

An alternative but similar approach is to use `ValueFromPipeline` to accept an input object, and then get the property values from that object:

```
function Test-Pipeline {
  [CmdletBinding ()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][Object]$InputObject
  )

  $Name = $InputObject.Name
  $Value = $InputObject.Value

  Write-Host "Name: $Name"
  Write-Host "Value: $Value"
}

$MyObject = [pscustomobject]@{
    Name = "MyName"
    Value = "MyValue"
}

$MyObject | Test-Pipeline
```

Some cmdlets will support both of these approaches, as PowerShell will try to match by object type first and then will revert to matching by property name. There's a detailed explanation of this here if you'd like to know more: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/03/25/learn-about-using-powershell-value-binding-by-property-name/

Note if you are going to work with values successfully via the Pipeline you also need to use a `Process { }` block in your function, which results in collections of objects being processed one at a time:

```
function Test-Pipeline {
  [CmdletBinding ()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][Object]$InputObject
  )

  Process {
      $Name = $InputObject.Name
      $Value = $InputObject.Value

      Write-Host "Name: $Name"
      Write-Host "Value: $Value"
  }
}

$MyObject = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = "MyName"
        Value = "MyValue"
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = "MySecondName"
        Value = "MySecondValue"
    }
)

$MyObject | Test-Pipeline
```

Without this only the last value in the object collection would be handled.

Comment: Nicely done; quibble: the word _value_ in `ValueFromPipepline` is unrelated to _value types_; it simply refers to binding the input object _as a whole_, irrespective of whether it is an instance of a value type or a reference type.

Comment: While your solution does answer the question, it requires to create a custom object beforehand. Would it be possible somehow to use a hashtable since the content is defined as "Key" or "Name" and "Value"? I am currently using an  intermediairy function to format the hashtable into the custom objects array which is not ideal.

Comment: You can send a single hash table to the same named parameters in a cmdlet via splatting. It doesn’t use the pipeline but I think it might be what you’re looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Mark's answer, as mentioned ValueFromPipeline attribute can be set only once per parameter type.
This is the example where multiple ValueFromPipeline are used, each for a different parameter type.

Only one parameter is assigned per iteration. The one matching the input value's type.

Note:
$Int contains `0` when no specific value is used on initialization.
It's safer to check which parameter set was used and not only if value was assigned.

```
function testus() {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ParameterSetName = "A")]
    [String]$Str,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ParameterSetName = "B")]
    [Int]$Int
  )
  process {
    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'A') {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "String was used:"
        Write-Host "Str: $Str"
        Write-Host "(Int contains initialized default value '0': $Int)"
    } elseif ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'B') {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Integer was used:"
        Write-Host "Int: $Int"
        Write-Host "(Str contains initialized default value '' (empty string): $($Str.gettype().FullName))"
    }
  }
}

'a', 1, 0 | testus
```